# C# Regex quick help

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a text file, and then break it up by each line thats is split by a "\n".  Then Regex it  and write out the regex.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        string[] firefox = filename.Split("\r\n");
        string prefix = prefix = Regex.Match(firefox, @"(\d)").Groups[0].Value;
        File.AppendAllText(workingdirform2 + "configuration.txt", prefix);
```

string[] firefox = filename.Split("\r\n"); doesnt exactly work.

What I want to do is run a regex foreach line of contents and then write out each line after the regex

So...

filename:
Hero123
Hero243
Hero5959

writes out to:
13
243
5959

Well everybody is suggesting something off the base in which i started.  the ending result will be about a 20 line regex with Ints.  I've got to parse it out line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx)

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(originalPath);
File.WriteAllLines(newPath, lines
    .Select(l => Regex.Match(l, @"\d+").Value).ToArray());
```

Comment: i'm getting all types of cannot converts, can you give me an example.

Comment: There's a fine line between fishing and just standing on the shore like an idiot. --Steven Wright

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code:

The reason the splitting doesn't work, is because you're splitting `filename`, not `contents`, which contains the actual file data. I agree with the other poster on using [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) :) It's a little more flexible with the file format compared to using `\r\n`, amongst other things.

Also, you have `string prefix = prefix = ...`, the second equals sign is probably intended to be a `+`. You should using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28VS.80%29.aspx) if the data files can become large, or better yet, write to an output stream as you go.

Passing an array to `Regex.Match` doesn't work either. To apply the regex to all lines, you should do something like:

```
foreach (string line in firefox)
{
    prefix = prefix + Regex.Match(line, // etc
    // Or rather:
    // stringBuilder.AppendLine(...)
}
```

Either that, or do it all at once with a multiline regex :)